# Route www subdomain traffic to https domain cloudfront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, web-hosting

I have a domain say **example.com** paired with Cloudfront and S3 to host a static website. The problem is while https://example.com and http://example.com are working fine but **[www.example.com](http://www.example.com)** is not working.

How can I add the config to route the traffic correctly from **www** sub-domin also? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the below steps to satisfy your requirement:

- In **N-Virginia** region Open ACM (Certificates Manager), request a certificate for `test.example.com`, and add `www.test.example.com` as an alternate domain (@ Add another name to this certificate)
- Open created certificate and click on `Create Records in Route53`, then wait for it to succeed.

[image: Create SSL Certificate for Sub Domains]

- Open your Cloudfront Distribution
- Click on Edit Under `General tab` > `Settings`
- Make sure you add two required domains in alternate domain names.
- Choose a newly created certificate under `Custom SSL Certificate`
- Then save, and wait for it to Deploy
- Then you can add route53 record for `www.test.example.com` domain

  - A Record
  - Choose the alias checkbox
  - Choose your CloudFront distribution

[image: Update Cloudfront Distribution]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I followed these steps but still the www subdomain is not working.

Comment: I just checked after some time, the www subdomain is working now! Thanks!

Comment: That's Cool....